# How to avoid Avoid Rebuilding DOM for nGFor using trackBy function - Angular Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a polling app. I have used *ngFor for looping the poll data and whenever I try to add or update a vote. The value of the vote changes but the whole DOM is rebuilding (refreshing). How to avoid rebuilding the whole DOM and to update the vote values. I tried using trackBy function. But it's not working properly.

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.postsCol=this.afs.collection('posts', ref => ref.where('postid', '==',this.id));
    this.posts = this.postsCol.valueChanges();
    this.posts = this.postsCol.snapshotChanges()
      .map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Posts;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          postId=id;
          return { id, data };
        });
      });
      this.pollsCol=this.afs.collection("posts").doc(this.id).collection("polls",ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp'));
      this.polls = this.pollsCol.valueChanges();
      this.polls = this.pollsCol.snapshotChanges()
      .map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Polls;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          pollId = id;
          return { id, data };
        });
      });
}

public trackByFn(poll){
  console.log("trackby"+poll);
  return poll;
}
```

---

```
  <div *ngFor="let poll of polls | async ; trackBy: trackByFn">
                  <div>

              <img [src]="poll.data.pollimage" class="mainpollimage">
              <br><br>
              <li><p class="mainpolltitle">{{ poll.data.polltitle}}</p>
              <p class="mainpollcontent">{{poll.data.pollcontent}}</p>
              <div class="votebox d-flex justify-content-start">
              <p class="mainpollvotes" ng-attr-id="{{poll.id}}" id="{{poll.id}}">{{poll.data.votes}} Votes</p>
              <div class="ml-auto" >
              <a    (click)="addVote(post.id,poll.id)" class="btn-floating btn-sm blue-gradient  ml-auto" ><i class="fa fa-star voteicon"></i></a>
              </div></div>
            </li>
            <br>
            <br>
            </div>
            </div>
```

How to display updated values without refreshing/ rebuilding the DOM? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since in your trackBy function you are returning the object that you get as input parameter, you are doing the same as the default of ngFor: comparing the object reference. Whenever the observable gets triggered with new values you get new object references for all your objects.
You need something that identifies your object. Since you are mapping to objects with id and data properties you can use the id of your objects.
Furthermore the method signature of the trackBy function is with 2 parameters... the index and the item of the array itself.

```
public trackByFn(index, poll){
  return poll.id;
}
```